# rails model association in nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have two models, Question which `has_many` Answers and Answers which `belongs_to` question. If in my Users model I add `has_many` Questions, would Users then automatically has_many Answers as well, or would I need to add `has_many` Answers manually?

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the "has many through" relationship. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically.  For users to have many answers, you'd want to use `:through`, e.g.,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, through: :questions
end
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to add: has_many :answers, through: :questions in this case because an user will have many answers that not acctually belongs to that user, they belongs to a question. In this case I think you should add has_many Answers normally

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your criticism.  Please elaborate.

Comment: I think he means (and now I'm wondering too) that there's no real point doing through: :questions for answers because the answers for a particular question are pertinent for that question only.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following setup:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end

class Question << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

You can't get to all user's answers with a single method. You would have to get all questions as a collection and then iterate through your questions collection and get all the answers. This would obviously lead to `N+1` query problem.

```
@user.questions.map(&:answers).flatten
```

To solve that `N+1` query problem, you'd have to use `.includes()`, but again that would only solve the `N+1` problem.

```
@user.questions.includes(:answers)
```

### Solution: use `has_many :through`

If you add `has_many :through` into your `User` model:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, through: :questions
end
```

This would allow you to access your user's answers with a single method like this:

```
@user.answers
```